# In Angular, how to I get the correct coordinates of an element after routing change?

Tags: angular, angular-router, elementref

I have a very small basic angular (14) SPA with a couple of routes. I'm using @ViewChild to get the coordinates of a particular element:

```
 @ViewChild('testElement', { static: true }) testElement!: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
```

and then

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    var position = this.fadeInText.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    var y = position.top; // (etc)
}
```

What I've noticed is that I get incorrect y values if I return to the route after going to another route.

However, if I check the positions again in ngAfterViewChecked after it has fired at least once before, I get the correct position values.

Is there a better way to handle this? I can't seem to find any other documentation on this issue.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try `ChangeDetectorRef`?

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly - No, I'm not sure how that would work in this context, or what event we'd attach it to that isn't already firing. I would have expected that the element position would have settled afterViewInit, but it doesn't until the afterView is checked twice. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

It can takes a moment for the DOM to render completely. A short `setTimeout` will probably work

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
       this.positionCalculations()
    }, 20)
}
```

You could also use an `RxJS` `timer(20)` rather than setTimeout, that way you can add a `takeUntil` in case routes change very fast

Comment: Appreciate the response. I'm hoping for a more event driven solution as delaying the calculation may work most of the time, but doesn't guarantee the desired result.

Comment: I ended up using my original method, I'm not sure I see an advantage one way or the other between yours and mind. Both seem like they're trying to get around a problem without an elegant solution.